# About regex in Java (Very simple, but I don't know why it doesn't work

Tags: java, regex

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9]","@#%abc"));
}
```

This is very very simple code about regex in Java.

As far as I know, [^A-Za-z0-9] should return true when it matches with any special characters because [^ means the negation and A-Za-z0-9 means all characters including numbers. I don't know why above code keeps returning false, instead of true.

Comment: How could the code return `true` when you clearly have `abc` in there? `matches` means "the whole input sequence matches the pattern". And yes, it's missing a `+` (due to @Sean below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a +:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9]+.*","@#%abc"));
// no, this will only match the first few characters,
// added wildcard to catch the rest
```

`Pattern.matches()` implies a full match, i.e. the entire pattern matches the text from beginning to end. In your case you are doing a find(), i.e. there are multiple matches of the Pattern in the text, but not a single full match, as your pattern matches only one character.

Answer (score 2):

Your match is attempting to match *one* character alone.

You should instead reconfgiure the match to indicate the first character and the rest you don't care about e.g.

```
Pattern.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9].*","@#%abc")
```

Note the **.*** after your match on the first character.

Comment: yeah, but the + alone won't work, because abc are non-matching characters, so your original aproach is better